# text renders in black when it's red in 3d view, why?

Tags: rendering, materials, 3d-view, text-object, color

I want to make this text red, which it is in the view port but when i render it out as a PNG image sequence and add it as a image sequence in the VSE it comes up black.

I've tried tickering with options such as ticking object colour, making the texture and materail colour the same, getting rid of the secular light but nothing works and im getting really frustrated.

I'll link my blend file here: [image]

Here's my original question which this problem arised from: [how do i achieve this simple text animation?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/69970/how-do-i-achieve-this-simple-text-animation/70527#70527)

any help with the original question ive linked would be a huge help as the person who i followed the answer to before has gone silent so i'm stuck.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's no light source in your scene. What you can do is give your text's material an emit value (in this case 1).

[image: Emit]

Or alternatively you could check the "Shadeless" option.

Comment: cheers that solved my problem, close the books on this one!