# How do I roll a tube on itself down the sides?

Tags: modeling, mesh, objects

I'm trying to model an object where the 2D tube shape it rolled up along the sides, similarly to how you roll your sleeves up

[image: Rough Sketch of cross-section]

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Reduce Curve Deformation](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/64954/reduce-curve-deformation)

Answer (score 2):

You could start with a plane and delete one side.

[image: Add plane delete edges]

Then add a Subsurf modifier to make the curl smooth. Add a Cast modifier driven by an empty. Then a screw modifier to wrap the distorted edge around into a tube.

[image: Curled edge]

[image: Tube]

Answer (score 2):

Create a Bezier curve. Open edit mode, rotate it by 90 degrees in Y and 90 degrees in Z by, offset it in X direction, add a screw modifier and edit it from front view. You can add a solidify modifier afterwards.

The cool thing about bezier curves is that they are a bit more flexible than regular polygons.